# I was trying to fetch get all the compute instances list using google cloud REST API. I get the below error while filtering with jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am trying fetch get all the compute instances list using google cloud REST API. I have some information in a file.json.

Example file.json

```json
"zones/me-west1-c": {
    "warning": {
      "code": "NO_RESULTS_ON_PAGE",
      "message": "There are no results for scope 'zones/me-west1-c' on this page.",
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "scope",
          "value": "zones/me-west1-c"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

When I run the below command I get the following error.

```
cat file.json | jq .items.zone/me-west-c
```

```
jq: error: me/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.items.zones/me-west1-c             
jq: error: west1/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.items.zones/me-west1-c                
jq: error: c/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.items.zones/me-west1-c
```

Can someone help me to where exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: So use something like [`."zones/me-west1-c".warning.message`](https://jqplay.org/s/Bo46LqbJTi2)

Comment: Thank you @0stone0 i was able to get the output as desired